# Execute command in background and get notified when done, with time of execution

Tags: linux, unix, shell

How do I make sure I get notified when the job is done?

Here is what I'm running:

```
$ time find -exec chmod o-r '{}' \+&
```

I would like to know how long the job took and be notified when it is done.

I thought of doing this:

```
$ time ls -l 2>&1 | write buttlebutkus pts/0&
```

(Using `ls -l` to do a quick test)

But the result was kind of `weird`. Though it did seem to essentially work, but I'm afraid maybe only because the `ls` sent an `EOF` to the `write`.

EDIT:

I just tried this:

```
$ time find -exec chmod o-r '{}' \+ 2>&1 | write buttlebutkus pts/0&
```

Now I am seeing millions of pages of output and cannot get away from it with either ctrl-z or ctrl-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ time find -exec chmod o-r '{}' \+ 2>&1 && write buttlebutkus pts/0 &
```

[**`man bash`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
   The control operators && and ││ denote AND lists and OR lists, respectively.  An AND list has the form

          command1 && command2

   command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was going to ask you why `&&`. Thank you for adding the quote from man bash. I would have never thought of using that operator. Perfect!

Comment: By the way, am I interpreting the `2>&1` correctly? Do I even need that for this to work? If you have any link that helps explain that syntax I would appreciate that too.

Comment: `2>&1` means that redirect stderr to stdout, and display both on the terminal.